# How to track different conversation threads between 2 participants in twilio?

Tags: twilio, sms

I have an application which uses Twilio to send SMSs.

There is a situation where the application sends multiple messages to a person, for example a message with info about product P1, then another message with information about product P2, and so on. So my question is, when the person replys the SMS, how could I know to exactly what SMS he is replying?

Or is it possible that each SMS that my application sends to the same person creates different conversations in Twilio,  so I can track each response per each different SMS?, if so, how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger the SMS messages by API it's hard to know what messages the customers answer.

We got to solve this problem using Twilio Sync (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/api/document-resource) which is basically cloud storage, so when we need to trigger an SMS or Whatsapp message, we save some information on Twilio Sync, like Twilio number, client number and the messages that were sent.

When the customer answers the message, we send him to a Twilio Studio that runs a Function that read the Sync document and check if this customer comes from a message response, if yes, we get the triggered message and added on the conversations, so we know the message that customer answered.

The Sync isn't a database and has a limit, so depending on your message volume, it can not work well.